# react does not recognize the 'fullWidth' prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

- **error Screenshot**

[image]

[image]

[image]

- I used `fullWidth` as a property. when I remove those, I see also the error.
- I used `isLoading` as a variable, not a prop.
- I didn't use `colorKey` in our code. but found this error for `colorKey`.
- **Where am I using `fullWidth` `isLoading` is given below**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
**- There is no `colorKey`.**

I need to know which topic I can check to solve this error. any clue? any suggestion to get rid of this error?

#### Source code: https://github.com/CrazyPythonLover1/africaswap-interface-master/tree/main/src

#### Technology: React, styled-components, TypeScript.

Comment: You're somehow passing those props down to DOM elements.

Comment: How to find, where I am passing those props. I am searching in VS code for whole with ctrl+shift+f

Comment: I think it's the library you're using, pancakeswap

Comment: yes, it is a library

Comment: How to solve this kind of problem? any Idea. I am have been searching for 3 days

Comment: One option is to create an issue directly for the maintainers of the package: https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-uikit/issues

Answer (score 1):

Without needing to specifically look into your Pancake UI library (The same problem you're facing happens with Material-UI for example);
The library is passing properties to its children which are part of the library for some reason on to children DOM nodes without getting filtered out. You can circumvent this by creating a simple additional component that only renders the necessary props to its children.

This is a generic example, in case you want to render a div only only want the style to stay:

```
const RemoveDomProps=({style,children})=>(<div style={style}>{children}</div>)
```

Then you'd use it as a wrapper inside your code:

```
<MyUILibraryComponent>
    <RemoveDomProps style={{...}}>
        {...}
    </RemoveDomProps>
</MyUILibraryComponent>
```

Answer (score -3):

Just find where you are using `fullWidth` by pressing `Ctrl`+`f` and search *fullWdth* and replace it with *fullwidth*